# How to match all double quotes inside double quoted values?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

As I am trying to improve my regular expression skills, I am trying to solve this use case.

Let's say a server delivers an incorrectly formatted JSON string and we want to convert this string so that we can convert it to JSON:

```
let x = '{"my_text":"hello "world"","test2":"tree","blue":"red "yellow","orange":"green, purple "cyan""}';
```

I have a regex that matches all double quotes inside double quotes, except for the ones around `cyan`.

```
/(?<=\:\"([^\,\"]*))\"(?=([^\,]*)\"\,)/g
```

If I am correct, it is because `[^\:\"]` excludes either `:` or `"`, while I want to exclude them sequentially (`:"`) from the positive lookbehind.

Now I've thought about doing a negative lookbehind after the positive lookbehind, but it's not matching and I'm not sure why:

```
/(?<=\:\")(?<!(.*)\:\"(.*))\"(?=([^\,]*)\"\,?)/g`
```

Am I missing something? How do I match all double quotes inside double quoted values?

Comment: Is that supposed to be valid JSON? That's not how quotes work inside JSON strings.

Comment: Is it possible to correct the format of the input string? I'd suggest doing that if possible instead of wasting X amount of time trying to get good output from garbage input

Comment: @tadman This is not valid JSON. This is a resulting string I am receiving from a server which does not deliver properly and I am trying to use regular expressions to replace these mistakes in order to parse it as JSON. I'm looking for help please

Comment: Your time might be better spent figuring out why the server is producing bad results like that. It's strange.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would like to learn how to do this using regular expressions please. I believe I came far and would like to learn more in order to fix it

Comment: This is a broken response. I'm not sure you can actually fix this without looking at it subjectively as a human. Any regular expression you come up with will have to be infinitely complex, as there could be an undefined number of layers here of damage you need to undo.

Comment: To correctly parse some string like that, you have to understand the rules by which it is composed. If it is truly some kind of error in the server, there may be no predictable or reliable rules.

Comment: For example, how do you handle `""a,b",c","d,"e,"f""""`? If you're trying to repair a defect where there are only so many cases to cover, maybe a regex can fix it, but it's asking a lot of a regex. These sorts of repairs usually depend on interpreting the mess you have, and picking the most *probable* interpretation, while a regex can only pick the best match.

Comment: Well, the server may deliver wrongly, but that is not my question. I am asking because I am trying to improve my regex skills because I enjoy it. I am looking for someone who is able to teach me how to solve this using regex please.

Comment: This is nothing that can easily be fixed. Especially not with regex because regex are very bad at matching nested structures. I agree with the other comments here: If there is any possibility this could be fixed at the backend where this garbage is created, fix it there ...

Comment: So you're saying that I've pretty much reached the limits of regex here? Congratulations to me then :) I guess I've learned enough

Comment: @Zoq there's an extensive amount of theory behind the capabilities of different kinds of grammar recognizers. Regular expressions, even the extended ones common today, cannot recognize all types of grammars. Different parsing systems are required.

Comment: A reason for the second pattern not to match for example is that it asserts this `(?<=:")` and matches `"` so it is trying to match a string like this `:""` Note that you are using capture groups inside the lookarounds, and that you don't have to use all those escapes, and that your actual "match" is just a double quote, and this opens pandora's box https://regex101.com/r/vqE1YX/1

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own question - despite comments.

```
let x = '{"my_text":"hello "world"","test2":"tree","blue":"red "yellow","orange":"green, purple "cyan""}';

x = x.replaceAll( /(?<![\,\:\{])\"(?![\:\,\}])/g, '\\"' );

const j = JSON.parse( x );
console.log('j:', j)
```

The regex pattern is inverted to exclude the double quotes that should be there.

This may not be a perfect solution as others pointed out, due to its vulnerabilities for other potential issues being delivered from the server. But at least it is solving the issue in question.

In the mean time I am waiting for a response from the third party serving this API output and see if they are able to solve it on their end.

**Result**

[image]